# I have this error, when it loads the tests of a specific container (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nonce'))

Tags: testing, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vitest

I am carrying out the tests in vitest of a repo, locally everything happens ok, but when I load a test that only calls another component it generates this error:

```
⎯⎯⎯⎯ Unhandled Rejection ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nonce')
 ❯ eval node_modules/happy-dom/src/nodes/html-script-element/HTMLScriptElementUtility.ts:50:38
 ❯ eval node_modules/happy-dom/src/nodes/html-script-element/HTMLScriptElementUtility.ts:50:38
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
 ❯ Function.loadExternalScript node_modules/happy-dom/src/nodes/html-script-element/HTMLScriptElementUtility.ts:50:38
 ❯ processTicksAndRejections node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5
```

This error originated in `"src/apps/payments/views/PaymentLink/__test__/Detail.spec.ts"` test file. It doesn't mean the error was thrown inside the file itself, but while it was running.

Apparently the error is related to the Detail file, but I already validated routes and everything and it's ok

Test of Detail Container -----------------

```
import { shallowMount, VueWrapper } from '@vue/test-utils';

import Detail from '@/apps/payments/views/PaymentLink/Detail.vue';
import PaymentLinkDetail from '@/payments/presentation/containers/PaymentLinks/PaymentLinkDetail.vue';

describe('Detail view', () => {
  let wrapper: VueWrapper<any>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(Detail, {});
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    vi.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('should render the Detail view container', async () => {
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should contain the PaymentLinkDetail view container', async () => {
    expect(wrapper.findComponent(PaymentLinkDetail).exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Detail Container

```
<template>
  <PaymentLinkDetail />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import PaymentLinkDetail from '@/payments/presentation/containers/PaymentLinks/PaymentLinkDetail.vue';
</script>
```

Comment: Do you expect anyone to know what's in those files? Consider creating a [mcve]. Use codesandbox or a similar service.